# zsh completion - substring on results from custom script

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Let's say I have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
hello() { 
  echo "Hello $1!" 
}

hello_list() {
  echo "${1}foo"
  echo "${1}bar"
  echo "foo${1}bar"
  echo "foobar${1}"
}

_hello() { 
  compadd $(hello_list ${words[2]})
} 

compdef _hello hello
```

if I type `hello bob<TAB>` I get:

```
bobbar  bobfoo
```

From my reading of the docs, I think this is because I have `zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list ''` in one of my many `ohmyzsh` config files.

How can I get a list that appears based on a substring match when I press tab?
I am really struggling to understand the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `_hello` to this:

```
_hello() { 
  compadd -M 'l:|=* r:|=*' $(hello_list ${words[2]})
}
```

I stumbled across some notes in section 6.7.5 here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide06.html that led me to this. That link indicates that you can enable substring matches with `zstyle` settings, but I couldn't get any of those to work on my system.